# std::variant comparison with std::nullptr_t inside

Tags: c++, c++17

My problem can be summarised in following code

```cpp
#include <variant>

int main()
{
    using V = std::variant<int, std::nullptr_t>;
    V a = 0;
    V b = nullptr;

    a < b;
}
```

I want to have variant with `std::nullptr_t` inside and I want to be able to compare such variants. It was working on Visual Studio 2018 (version 16.1.X), but it won't compile on version 16.3.1. I thought that this is a bug in the compiler, but I'm not sure now. I cannot find anything about `std::nullptr_t` supporting comparison operators and even [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/eAobBT) and [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/hux8DK) seems to disagree. Should it be working, or not? Also, if no is the correct answer, is there a way to make it work? Defining of the operator for `std::nullptr_t` doesn't seem to work.

```cpp
inline bool operator<(std::nullptr_t, std::nullptr_t)
{
    return false;
}
```

As defining relational operators can be done only on class parameter.

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't that operator mean that `nullptr != nullptr`? Wouldn't that be really bad?

Comment: you try to call `operator<` but define `operator==` is taht a typo?

Comment: @François Andrieux: You are right, but it doesn't matter, since it won't compile.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your use case for  `std::nullptr_t` in a `std::variant`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type `std::nullptr_t` does not have any relational operators defined for it. It is only equality-comparable (that is `nullptr == nullptr` is valid and `true`, but `nullptr < nullptr` is ill-formed). You could argue that this is a defect, and we could define the relational operators such that `nullptr < nullptr` is `false` and `nullptr <= nullptr` is `true`, etc. But that is the way it is.

Using `<` on `variant<Ts...>` requires `<` to be a valid operation on each type in `Ts...`, which is not the case in your example, hence `a < b` is ill-formed. This isn't a bug in any of the compilers or the libraries, it's the expected behavior.

---

The only way to make `<` work here is to provide types that actually have a `<` - that is, wrap `std::nullptr_t` in some other type that actually is ordered. Do you need specifically `std::nullptr_t`? Maybe `std::monostate`, which has all six comparisons, is a better choice?

Comment: OK, suppose it make sense, but how to go around that? Because it seems like there is no easy way to do it :(.

Comment: Well I'm actually trying to represent something like json, so I have `std::monostate` for undefined, `std::nullptr_t` for null, `double` for number, etc. And it worked perfectly, but with new Visual Studio they fixed something and it breaks. So, I suppose adding new type can solve it.

Comment: @koscelansky if you just need a sentinal representing empty you can use anything, eg `struct my_null {};`

Comment: @koscelansky I wouldn't reuse those `std` types for representing your JSON values. `std::nullptr_t` represents a null pointer, but a JSON `null` is not really a pointer. The same way, `undefined` in JSON is not really `std::monostate` either (a type used to represent the empty value in `std::variant`).

Comment: @Acorn: Fair enough for JSON, but I'm trying to represent _something like_ JSON, but not quite and since it is used in C++ and for C++ code I though why not use what I can from the language, but now I see, that for null I need a new type.

Comment: @koscelansky If you actually want a *null-state* `std::optional` might not be the worst idea. In your case probably `std::optional<std::variant<...>>`.